# Сокращение слов

Tags: грамотная-речь, недопустимая-метка

Подскажите возможно ли в схеме задачи по арифметике 1го класса , слово «яиц» обозначить буквой «Я» . Просто для того что бы ребенок на начальном этапе понял , что обозначает, та или другая сумма . Будет ли это считаться ошибкой ? Или такой вариант допустим ?

Comment: Обозначение буквой, это не сокращение, а операция замены. И это уже ближе к алгебре, а не арифметике. Сокращение, это когда слова в тексте урезаются, а тут не текст, а математическое выражение будет, если я вас правильно понял. Математическая запись это не совсем тоже самое, что язык речи. Поэтому правила русского языка и тп., могут не совсем сочетаться с правилами математической записи и наоборот.